# TKinter CSV file with common header

Tags: tkinter, graphcool

Anybody know this error

```
Traceback(most recent call last): 
    File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkint __init__.py", line 1883, 
        in __call__ return self.func(*args) 
    File "projtk.py", 
        line 125, in action dict_writer.writerow({File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/csv.py", 
        line 154, in writerow returnself.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict)) 
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/csv.py", 
        line 149, in _dict_to_list raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: " 
    ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'user Age', 'userName', 'user Email Address'}
```

Comment: Please do proper code formatting, so the Q is better and please include your error lines too

Comment: My Code is

tool_bar = ttk.Label(main_application)
tool_bar.pack(side=tk.TOP, file=tk.X)
font_tuple = tk.font.families()
font_family = tk.StringVar()
font_box = ttk.Combobox(tool_bar, width=30, textvariable=font_family, state='readonly')
font_box['values'] = font_tuple
font_box.current(font_tuple.index('Arial'))
font_box.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
size_var = tk.IntVar()
font_size = ttk.Combobox(tool_bar, width=14, textvariable= size_var, state='readonly')
font_size['value'] = tuple(range(8,80,2))
font_size.current(4)
font_size.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

Comment: Error I recived is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vpad.py", line 68, in <module>
    tool_bar.pack(side=tk.TOP, file=tk.X)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2387, in pack_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-file": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side

Comment: what does the `file = tk.X` argument mean?

Comment: Please don't post code and tracebacks in the comment section. Instead, [edit] your question to include the additional information.